# Express: Extending request.query with declaration merging throws TypeScript error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Can I extend the express **request query** object in that way by using declaration merging?

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface Request {
        query: {
            provider: string[];
        };
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
myController.get(
    "/",
    (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
        const doStuffToArray = (array: string[]) => array.reduce((item) => item)
        const { provider } = request.query;

        doStuffToArray(provider);
```

This throws
`Type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.`

Using generics like below works by the way.

```
async (
    request: express.Request<
        {},
        {},
        {},
        { provider: string[] }
    >,
    response: express.Response,
) => {
```

Comment: I didn't find any usage of 'request' or 'response' in `Example usage`

Comment: @Anatoly My bad, the destructuring statement went missing. I added it `const { provider } = request.query;`

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that `provider` will always be `string[]` then you can do `doStuffToArray(provider as string[])`